# Can I use SQL to balance 'IN' transactions against 'OUT' transactions?

Tags: sql, business-intelligence

Fair warning, I am very new to this and am likely going about things altogether the wrong way. Sorry for my formatting.

I am working with an SQL database that manages all inventory and transactions within the company. Using the transaction log (`translog`), I want to be able to identify how many parts exist in a current location by balancing the 'OUT' and 'IN' quantities.

Effectively, I have a table like this:

| ITEMNO | LOT_NO | TRANS_IN_OUT | TRANS_QUAN | LOC_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adpa01 | 156222 | IN | 21 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa01 | 156222 | OUT | 21 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa01 | 156222 | IN | 22 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa02 | 156133 | IN | 21 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa02 | 156134 | IN | 21 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa02 | 156133 | OUT | 11 | IN_TRANSIT |
| Adpa01 | 156223 | IN | 21 | IN_TRANSIT |

At minimum, I'm hoping for the output:

| ITEM_NO | LOT_NO | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adpa01 | 156222 | 22 |
| Adpa02 | 156133 | 11 |
| Adpa02 | 156134 | 21 |
| Adpa01 | 156223 | 21 |

I got as far as a basic query filtering out the results that I'm trying to work with.

Newbie code:

```
Select TRANSLOG.ITEMNO,
  TRANSLOG.TRANS_QUAN,
  TRANSLOG.LOC_DESC,
  TRANSLOG.LOTNO
From TRANSLOG
Where TRANSLOG.ITEMNO Like '<filter>' And TRANSLOG.TRANS_QUAN > 0 And
  TRANSLOG.LOC_DESC Like 'IN TRANSIT'
Order By TRANSLOG.ITEMNO
```

My concept is to sum the 'IN' quantities minus the 'OUT' quantities for each unique Lot Number, but I'm not sure if I'm just making things more difficult than they need to be.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can something like this help you? `SELECT ITEMNO, (IF TRANS_IN_OUT = 'IN' THEN TRANSLOG.TRANS_QUAN ELSE -TRANSLOG.TRANS_QUAN) SIGNED_QTY FROM TRANSLOG` as a sub query, and then use `SELECT ..., SUM(SIGNED_QTY) FROM (SELECT <above query>) ... GROUP BY ITEMNO`

Comment: Or just `sum(Case When trans_in_out='OUT' Then -qty Else qty End) as Onhand`, and `group by Itemno, Lot_no`

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Add or subtract from total using CASE conditions in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446999/90527)", "[On demand count inventory scan efficiently in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54243544/90527)", "[Conditionally summing/subtracting quantities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52300868/90527)"

Comment: ... "[SQL conditional addition or subtraction](//stackoverflow.com/q/1429769/90527)", "[Calculate the amount money using SQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/61161894/90527)"